# using variable names instead of predictor names in emmeans call

Tags: r, emmeans

Let's say I have defined a variable (`var`) which is the name of a predictor in the model

```
libary(emmeans)
var <- "disp"
lm.mod <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data=mtcars)
```

When I try to use the variable `var` in the `at` argument of `emmeans`, it gets ignored

```
emmeans(lm.mod, var, at=list(var=c(100,200,300,400)))
 disp emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
  231   20.1 0.553 29       19     21.2
```

using `disp` instead, I get the expected output:

```
emmeans(lm.mod, var, at=list(disp=c(100,200,300,400)))
 disp emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
  100   24.1 1.115 29     21.8     26.3
  200   21.0 0.598 29     19.8     22.2
  300   18.0 0.754 29     16.4     19.5
  400   15.0 1.370 29     12.2     17.8
```

Isn't it possible to use variables in place of the actual predictor names in the `at` argument of the `emmeans` call?

Comment: Try `emmeans(lm.mod, var, at=setNames(list(c(100,200,300,400)), var))`.

Comment: By the way, I'm trying variations of the `emmeans` call and I noticed that `var<-c("disp","hp")` `emmeans(lm.mod, list(var))` isn't the same as `emmeans(lm.mod, list("disp","hp"))` even though `emmeans` appears to understand that `var` contains two predictors. Is this to be expected?

Comment: @locus - compare the output of `list(var)` and `list("disp","hp")`.  They are not the same. Use `as.list(var)`.